# Why does Doctrine insist on persisting referenced managed entities?

Tags: doctrine-orm

According to Doctrine 2.0 docs (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html) a

> ..preexisting managed entity, is ignored by the persist operation. However, the persist operation is cascaded to entities referenced by X, if the relationships from X to these other entities are mapped with cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL (see “Transitive Persistence”)."

My understanding is that cascading to referenced *managed* entities should lead to referenced entities being ignored by the persist operation (case 3):

> Persistence by Reachability: Cascade Persist
>
> 1. New entities in a collection marked as cascade persist will be directly persisted by Doctrine.
> 2. New entities in a collection not marked as cascade persist will produce an Exception and rollback the flush() operation.
> 3. Collections without new entities are skipped.

This is however not what happens. I have a managed `Channel` entity with 1:n `Properties` and `Data` entities. When the `Channel` entity is created some properties are retrieved but not modified.

When I add data and persist the entity via

```
$channel->addData(new Model\Data($channel, $timestamp, $value));
$em->persist();
```

I can see SQL for writing the new `Data` entities but do also see updates to the existing `Properties` (with the old, unchanged value).

**Why does Doctrine (2.4.1) persist relationships of managed entities?**

The entity definitions look like below:

```
class Channel extends Entity {
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Data", mappedBy="channel", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @OrderBy({"timestamp" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $data = NULL;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct($type) {
        parent::__construct($type);
        $this->data = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add a new data to the database
     */
    public function addData(\Volkszaehler\Model\Data $data) {
        $this->data->add($data);
    }

    ...
}

abstract class Entity {

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Property", mappedBy="entity", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @OrderBy({"key" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $properties = NULL;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $type
     */
    public function __construct($type) {
        if (!Definition\EntityDefinition::exists($type)) {
            throw new \Exception('Unknown entity type: \'' . $type . '\'');
        }

        $this->properties = new Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: any luck with finding answer to your question? I have same problem: when I only need to persist `UserPreferences` entity which has _ManyToOne_ relationship to the `User` entity, when doing `$em->persist($user_preferences);` it also persists the `User` entity (which I do not want, an it is a waste of `UPDATE` sql operation)... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally out that Doctrine does *not* insist on persisting referenced managed entities.

In the case described above I had however modified the related entities (changed type on some of the properties) which Doctrine, due to its `===` comparison when computing the change sets, did interpret as update.

There is some discussion about using the `PostFlush` event to prevent this, but sofar not conclusive: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/382#issuecomment-43421295